# Setting a string as a ComboBox Item Java

Tags: string, jcombobox

I am doing a medication tracking app and one part of it is having a medication info page which users can edit their details. All the info is stored in the database and I retrieved the details beforehand. I have a combobox for diseaseName and I added an action Listener and when it is clicked, it will show the corresponding medication (String) that they had displayed before. I want to show it in a combo box . I tried casting the string to an object and use setSelectedItem but to no avail.

Is it the correct way to do it? Or is there any other way? Do you need my code too? Thanks in advance.